# font-not-found using xelatex in windows 10

Tags: fonts, xetex

With MiKTeX 2.9, I'm gonna use `Lucida` and/or `Jokerman Regular` fonts which exist in the font section of my Windows 10:

[image]

I've no problem with `Georgia` or `Garamond`, but this code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,kantlipsum}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}

\setromanfont{Lucida}
%\setsansfont{Jokerman Regular}

\begin{document}

\kant[1]

\end{document}
```

returns an error as follows:

```
fontspec error: "font-not-found" The font "Lucida" cannot be found. For immediate help type H <return>. \setromanfont{Lucida}
```

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Happy new year!

You are using wrong font names.

In the case of `Jokerman Regular`, just get rid of that `regular`. Additionally, `Lucida` is a family name for a class of fonts, and you need to pinpoint a particular member of this class such as `Lucida Calligraphy Italic`.

So you may finally end up with the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,kantlipsum}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}

% Either of the following
\setmainfont{Lucida Calligraphy Italic}
\setmainfont{Jokerman}

\begin{document}

\kant[1]

\end{document}
```

`Jokerman Regular`:

[image]

`Lucida Calligraphy Italic`:

[image]

Comment: How did you find out that `Regular` must be removed from the font name?

Comment: @A.Loc if you click on the font icon you circled, you should get a window with a font preview which gives the `Font Name` in the data in the top pane, this doesn't have "Regular" in this case.